# How do I add a custom snooze period to Windows Calendar notifications?

Tags: windows-10, calendar

In Windows 10, the Calendar app is integrated and tries to take over calendar features.  It produces a notification 15 minutes before an event, like this:

[image: Example event with option to snooze for 5 minutes.]

The 15 minute reminder is helpful, to go through the mental checklist of completing any last-minute preparations.  Most of the time, that checklist happens quickly as everything's already complete, and I'd like the next reminder 10 minutes later, i.e. 5 minutes before the meeting, which is the get-up-and-go reminder.  However, when I click in the area which says "5 minutes," as if to edit, I get a select-list with the following limited options:

[image: Snooze values are 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 1 hour, 4 hours, 1 day.]

**How can I add a "10 minutes" option to this list?**

Many of the events on my calendar are created by other people, so changing the default reminder time for calendar events I create will not be a good solution.  I would like to add a custom time to the Snooze option in Windows 10, or be able to edit the value of an existing option.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't appear to be a way.
The choices are mostly worthless for me..
Depending on circumstances, I may want to snooze until 10 mins before to days before a target date/time.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 'Almars and Clock' app is very primitive and it does not have the feature setting you're requesting.