# Is there a way to change the default snooze time in Windows Calendar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, calendar

The default `Snooze` value for the Windows 10 calendar is 5 minutes.  I'd love to be able to change the default to something else, like 15 minutes.  But I don't see anything in the UI to do that. Nor do I see anything obvious in the Registry.

Is this possible?

[image]

Note that this question is not about [adding a snooze time](https://superuser.com/questions/1318773/how-do-i-add-a-custom-snooze-period-to-windows-calendar-notifications).

Comment: If you mean the Outlook default reminder time, this is specified in *Tools > Options > Customize the appearance of the Calendar > Default reminder*.

Comment: @harrymc No.  The Calendar app that ships with Windows.

Comment: Wait for Microsoft to open source Windows Calendar ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to not exist yet.
Vote here for Windows:
https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/13887996-option-to-apply-default-snooze-time-for-reminders

and here for Mac:
https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/31817122-allow-the-default-snooze-time-for-calendar-reminde

Comment: it appears both of those links no longer exist. Was the issue closed or did they move somewhere?

Comment: @adamdport They stopped using uservoice.com for tracking these things. They might have been moved to Microsoft's website, but it's impossible to know for sure. More than likely, those user requests have just disappeared.

Comment: These seem to apply to Outlook, not to the built-in calendar app.